# How can I use if else statement instead of try and catch exception in this code

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, exception, try-catch

```
 int age=0,maleCount=0,totalNumberOfMembers=0,younger=1000;
   double sum=0;
    String gender,str;
    FileReader fr=null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
```

How can I use if and else statement instead of try and catch exception in this code

```
   // try and catch block to catch exception if file not found
    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader("MyData.txt");
        pw = new PrintWriter("Results.txt");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    File file = new File("MyData.txt");
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            // we just need to use \t as delimiter
            sc.useDelimiter("\t");
           str = sc.next().trim();
           if(!str.isEmpty()){
            age = Integer.parseInt(str);
            sum += age;
           }else{
               break;
           }
            if(age<younger)
                younger = age;
            sc.useDelimiter("\t");
            gender = sc.next().trim();
            if(gender.equals("Male"))
                maleCount++;
            sc.useDelimiter("\n");
            sc.next().trim();
            totalNumberOfMembers++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.write("Average age: "+sum/totalNumberOfMembers+"\n");
   pw.flush();
    pw.write("Youngest age: "+younger+"\n");
   pw.flush();
    pw.write("Number of male members: "+maleCount+"\n");
   pw.flush();
}
```

How can I use if else statement instead of try and catch exception in this code

Comment: you don't. Try-catch is not at all related to if-else

Comment: no need to add if else you can catch multiple exceptions for one try block

Comment: For opening `File`s and other resource type objects, you should also use the "try with resources" pattern, to ensure Files are closed and resources released, whatever else happens.